# How do 'clients' fit in with 'platform devices' and 'platform drivers'

Tags: linux, drivers, persistence

Reading about [the driver-model platform](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt), my understanding is that a platform driver is a static piece of kernel code that controls a platform device, which is a device which generally is always present in the system, as opposed to a driver composed of a kernel module, which can be loaded or removed at will and controls devices which might not always be connected. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127729/what-is-the-difference-between-device-driver-and-kernel-module) seems to support that statement.

If all this is true, I expect it's what I'm looking for. I am trying to write a kernel module which, among other things, needs to communicate with an external device over I2C. While the external device isn't always part of the system, the I2C bus IS, so it ought to be controlled by a platform driver. So rather than writing code in my module to directly control the I2C, I ought to be using the platform driver. I found what I believe to be the proper platform driver for the I2C bus on my platform [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-cadence.c), and it does use < linux/platform_device.h >, so that seems to be consistent.

However, in addition to this, when looking up I2C in general, I have seen reference to an I2C "client". From the name alone, this sounds like what I am trying to write now, a kernel module that *uses* the platform driver to communicate over I2C. However, in the documentation for the driver-model platform, nothing about a "client" is mentioned, so I don't know if this is correct or if it is some completely separate different model.

So how does a "client" kernel module fit into the driver-platform model for interfacing with hardware in Linux? Is my module supposed to instantiate a struct of the i2c_driver, or is that something done by the platform driver, and the module is supposed to create an interface to that?